# Algorithm for generation of Canonical represented integers

Tags: algorithms, number-theory

Is there a way to get `canonical representation` of an integer by algorithm?
I can get primes, but I don't know how to represent, for example, 1000 as 2^3×5^3. How can I compute the power of each prime number?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

Comment: @D.W. there are around 15 algorithms. I don't know which one could give canonical representation. Do you?

Comment: Not sure what "canonical" means in this case.  But somehow you were able (by hand) to figure out $1000 = 2^3 \times 5^3$.  Figure out what you did by hand.  That's the algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest algorithm to do this is to divide repeatedly by the prime, until the division no longer yields an integer.

Comment: Yes, but this algorithm doesn't seem to be efficient. Do we have more efficient solutions?

Comment: @cassandradied It depends on how big the number is which you start with as you can stop when the test divisor is more than the square root of the dividend.  For example the JavaScript at http://www.se16.info/js/factor.htm does this and is fairly fast for reasonable numbers (say up to 10^12).  There are faster methods and methods which handle larger numbers, such as the Java applet at http://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM

Comment: @cassandradied this algorithm is much more efficient than any general method for finding prime divisors.  I don't see why you oppose it.

Comment: @Henry could you link me the faster methods? I'm looking for solution for the numbers with 100 digits and more. There is no problem in memory or implementation. I need less complex solution in terms of algorithmic complexity. Could you imagine dividing all numbers from 1 to 100-digit-number with all primes in that range? I will mark your answer if no one will give others anyway tomorrow.

Comment: @bbejot for finding prime divisors I use trial division. In this task, I need only canonical representation of any positive number. I mean, let's assume that at some moment I already have all primes up to some number K. Now I need canonical representation of K.

Comment: @cassandradied that's what I'm saying.  once you have the prime divisors of a number, then calculating how many times each prime divides the number (what FrankW is solving) is computationally trivial.  Finding the prime divisors, which you've stated you can already do, is the hard part.

Comment: @bbejot is it not normal if I think that it's not so good solution? Well, if you say so, I will agree with you and Henry.

Answer (score 3):

What you're calling the canonical form is a consequence of the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) which states that every integer $n>1$ can be uniquely expressed (up to order) as a product, 
$$
n = p_1^{a_1}\ p_2^{a_2}\ \dots \ p_k^{a_k}
$$
where the $p_i$ are distinct primes. From a theoretical standpoint, this is particularly interesting since it's currently unknown whether or not there is an efficient algorithm to solve this problem (namely, an algorithm that runs in time polynomial in the number of digits of $n$). Nobody has come up with an efficient algorithm for factorization, but, unlike a lot of known "hard" problems, like the [traveling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), no one has provided a proof that factorization must be hard. While @FrankW's suggested algorithm can be slightly improved, as far as anyone presently knows there's no really efficient solution.